# How can I query the LoginHistory object from Apex?

Tags: logging

It is sort of available via the user interface, and sort of available via API calls (after v21), and sort of available via reports - but I want to actually query the object directly and drive functionality based on that. Is there any way to do this?

If not, how can I most effectively create and populate a parallel object that allows me to drive this functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have to query LoginHistory object. I just tried to execute this from 'Developer Console' and works nicely

```
system.debug([SELECT ApiType,ApiVersion,Application,Browser,ClientVersion,Id,LoginTime,LoginType,LoginUrl,Platform,SourceIp,Status,UserId FROM LoginHistory limit 12]);
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, querying LoginHistory wasn't working from the Force.com Explorer ...

Comment: I just tried to execute this from 'Developer Console' and works nicely

Comment: You would need to be using API version 21.0 or higher to access the LoginHistory records as it was introduced in the Spring '11 release.

Answer (score 4):

Go through [Login History Object](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_loginhistory.htm)